# Shortening javascript multiple element.style.<property> statements

Tags: javascript

I'm working with "clean" javascript (no libs) and I am wondering about how can I perhaps make the following sample code shorter:

```
const element = document.createElement("div");
element.style.width = "100px";
element.style.height = 100px;
element.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
element.style.border = "1px solid black";
element.borderRadius = "20px";
```

When there are enough style properties to handle it becomes this annoying block of code. If there was chaining involved (as in jQuery) I could have at east add some indentation that would have made it a little easier on the eyes when going through the code.

So basically i'm asking for a no-dependency javascript suggestion offering either a shorter method to write the above code, or a prettier style to write it in.

Thanks,
CodeAt30

Comment: use a class ... or is it all dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this can be considered as shorter, you can try to use [**Object#assign**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to set the properties.

```
Object.assign(element.style, {  
                                width: '100px',
                                height: '100px',
                                backgroundColor: 'pink',
                                border:"1px solid black"
                             });
```

Comment: Oh this is great, it gives a very clear view of the element(Object) in the code itself which is mainly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You said that it would be nice to have css chaining calls without using jQuery. Actually, it's pretty simple to put a simple function together that can do just this in plain old javascript.

I've created an example for you:

```
function createElement(type) {
    const elem = document.createElement(type);
    return {
        baseElement: elem,
        css: function(key, value) {
            this.baseElement.style[key] = value;
            return this;
        },
        toDOM: function() {
            return this.baseElement;
        }
    };
}
```

which you can then use like this:

```
function test() {
    var elem = createElement("div").css("width", "100px").css("height", "100px").css("backgroundColor", "pink").css("border", "1px solid black").css("borderRadius", "20px").toDOM();
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

You'd have to include this helper function as a "dependecy" but as you can just paste it into your own javascript, I don't think of it as a real dependency.

Here you can see it in action as well:

```js
function createElement(type) {
 const elem = document.createElement(type);
 return {
  baseElement: elem,
  css: function(key, value) {
   this.baseElement.style[key] = value;
   return this;
  },
  toDOM: function() {
   return this.baseElement;
  }
 };
}

function test() {
 var elem = createElement("div").css("width", "100px").css("height", "100px").css("backgroundColor", "pink").css("border", "1px solid black").css("borderRadius", "20px").toDOM();
 document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

Comment: Hey this is super nice. Thanks!